# URI build error when using org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder.URIBuilder.build()

Tags: java, http

my codes as follows:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http")
            .setHost("127.0.0.1:8080")
            .setPath("/test")
            .setParameter("openid", "openid")
            .setParameter("openkey", "openkey")
            .build();
```

i expect get the result like this:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?openid=openid&openkey=openkey
but sometimes the result is: http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?openid%3dopenid%26openkey%3dopenkey

i hope to get the reason why the "=","&" are encoded, thanks for you help

Comment: What do you mean 'sometimes the result is [different]'? It can't be random, something (probably the input) must be different in that case.

URIBuilder basically builds a string like the first example and then gives it to the URI(String) constructor (who might do some parsing and encoding of its own).

Can you give a better example (more code) of how you use this, where you see the second uri and what your input is in that case? I suspect a special character ('&' or '=' for example) in your input is the reason.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i mean the character "&" which separate the NameValuePairs and the character "=" between NameValuePair are encoded unexpected.

Comment: I understood that, I don't understand how it can be different only 'sometimes' and not 'all the time'. Encoding the exact same string shouldn't get different results every time (unless you are deliberately introducing randomness) so I suspect the difference is in the inputs. Which inputs go right (and what is their output) and which inputs go wrong (and what is their output)?

Can you add more code describing what exactly you are doing, how you are reading the string and how you are outputting them?

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the url with this code

```
URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.decode(uri, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))
```